# How can I get sum of grouped data with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, group-by, sum

I have a collection includes log data.

```
[
   {
      "logType":1,
      "created_at": 2015-12-15 07:38:54.766Z
   },
   ..
   .. 
   ..,
   {
      "logType":2,
      "created_at": 2015-13-15 07:38:54.766Z
   }
]
```

I want group by `created_at` field and get group element counts.

My goal is show infographic which includes total logs count by weekly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by week using [$week](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/week/) and [$year](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/year/):

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    {
      $group:{
         _id: {
           year: { $year:"$created_at" },
           week: { $week:"$created_at" }
         },
         count: { $sum:1 }
      }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, If I want group by day, what should I do? $day aggregate is available for this case?

Comment: You can add [$dayOfWeek](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/#exp._S_dayOfWeek) to your grouping.

Also you can use [$dayOfYear](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/#exp._S_dayOfYear) instead of $week in grouping.